# T-Sql Algorithm Question

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a T-Sql Statement as follows;

```
Insert into Table1
Select * From Table2
```

I want to know the running sequence. Does the insert waits select statement to finish before starting or it starts asap select statement starts returning values and expects new records from the select statement to continue.

This is a plain stored procedure and no transactions used.

Comment: +1 this is the first time I saw someone inserting its own values to its own table... I absolutely had no clue if it was possible... but it is...

Comment: @Sung: I'm not even sure it would have occurred to me to try this, but I'm definitely filing it away for future use; it's great way to generate one-off test data.

Comment: @Sung Meister actually I wrote wrong. Edited, insert into table1 not table2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To echo @CodeByMoonlight's answer, and to address your comment there: the *physical* considerations (including the specifics of locking) are always subordinate to the *logical* instructions specified by the query.

In the processing of an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement, *logically speaking* the `SELECT` is carried out to produce a resultset, and then the rows of this resultset are `INSERT`ed. The fact that in this case the source table and the target table are the same table is irrelevant. I'm fairly sure that specifying `NOLOCK` or `TABLOCK` would in any case apply only to the `SELECT`, if that's where you position them.

Consider as another example this statement, which makes no sense if you read it in an 'imperative' way:

```
UPDATE SomeTable
SET Column1 = Column2, Column2 = Column1
```

With an imperative, rather than set-based, understanding, this statement might look as if it will result in `Column1` and `Column2` having the same value for all rows. But it doesn't - it in fact **swaps** the values in `Column1` and `Column2`. Only by understanding that the *logical* instructions of the query dictate what actually happens can this be seen.

Answer (score 3):

What you have there is effectively a single statement. It will only insert into Table2 the records that were present in Table2 when you begin the insert. Otherwise the properties of [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) would not apply and you'd have issues with isolation (what if the sp is run twice concurrently) and durability. SQL Server will enforce this via locking.

Comment: What I don't get is, suppose that you have 10 records in `table2`.   then inserting with "insert table2 select * from table2 (nolock)" & "insert table2 select * from table(tablock)" seem to both insert 10 records.  Shouldn't "nolock" return whether a record is committed or not? I was thinking the former would generate an infinite loop